# Viewpager update on tabclick listener

Tags: android

I've a problem to update my viewpager on tabclick listener on second tab "CART", I want to update my list view in second fragment named "CART" via getting record from database table...

Here's my code in MainActivity:

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager){

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            super.onTabSelected(tab);
            int tab_index = tab.getPosition();
            if (tab_index == 1){
                     adapter.updateData();
                  // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
        }`private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "HOME");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "CART");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    public final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    public  void updateData(){
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    // Return the Fragment associated with a specified position..... Android calls getItem(...) only if it wants to create new Fragments.
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    //Return the number of views available.
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    // Called when the host view is attempting to determine if an item's position has changed.
    // Returns POSITION_UNCHANGED if the position of the given item has not changed or POSITION_NONE if the item is no longer present in the adapter.
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}`

Code in Fragment Two i.e. CART:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    DM = DB_Object.getInstance(getActivity());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two,container,false);
    listview_product = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_list);
    BindListView(DM);
    return view;
}

public void set_order_set_id(boolean order,String id){ is_order = order; unique_id = id; }

public void BindListView(DataManipulator DM_Obj)
{
    BindProducts = new ArrayList<ProductList>();
    ProductDetails = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    ProductDetails = DM_Obj.GetFromInventory();

    product_barcode = new String[ProductDetails.size()];
    product_price = new String[ProductDetails.size()];

    int i = 0;
    for(String[] product : ProductDetails )
    {
        product_barcode[i] = product[0];
        product_price[i] = product[1];

        BindProducts.add(new ProductList(product_barcode[i],product_price[i]));
        i++;
    }

    if (getActivity() != null) {
        list_adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), BindProducts);
       // listview_product = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.product_list);
        listview_product.setAdapter(list_adapter);
        // listview_product.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to update your list inside fragment, then you must  update your list inside  setUserVisibleHint() method of the fragment. because whenever your change your fragment this method calls every time. Notify your list adapter with new list in this method and you will get new updated list everytime.

Comment: can I call setUserVisibleHint() on tabistener ???

Comment: It will be called inside the fragments of viewpager

Comment: thank you :) it worked for me but there is also a method, updating viewpager why it not worked for me or is there any other senario for using this technique??

Comment: can you show me the method you are telling about so that i can explain you that in better way

Comment: See the updateviewpagermethod() that I've created  for the viewpager update... My Logic is to update method called when hits the tablistener event so notifyDataSetChange() will recreate the fragment so updated list would be acheived... what's the issue in this logic??

Comment: as i see your code... your update data will only notify the adapter things like list or fragment which you enter very first not the items inside fragment... it will update only the fragment or list which you add after you initialize the adapter. if you to want to do like this you have to pass your data list also with fragment as we do to transfer data from one fragment to another..

Comment: can you please give me an example code regarding my code so that I can manage my code

Comment: I never do like that... i prefer the setUservisibleHint() method..... for your specified way you always have to pass updated list as arguments with fragment which is not good approach....

Comment: **setUservisibleHint()** can also be used for other types of work in fragment ??? other than listview...... I mean to say let suppose fragment is rendered and **setUservisibleHint()** gives **TRUE**.... after that I have to do some work like button clicks or some other work so in that case all the working would be like same as of normal activity???

Comment: Yes... That depends on you what you want to do

Comment: I am new to android I want to learn android ASAP kindly guide me and give a route map

Comment: go through developer site  [link](https://developer.android.com)

Comment: you will find better approach from official developer site

Comment: I've an application running in landscape mode (i.e. fixed / locked) when I locked the screen then came back to application what method of activity life cycle will be called ??  because after unlocking the screen landscape automatically switches to portrait...

Comment: in landscape activity is recreated. So it switches to portrait. if you want to keep screen fix then in manifest keep activity's orientation to landscape